# Date parameters do not seem to work for the Stack Exchange API's tags endpoint

Tags: stackexchange-api

If I [request tag info without specifying `fromdate`/`todate` parameters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=c%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), I get back some data. EG:

```
{
    "has_synonyms": true,
    "is_moderator_only": false,
    "is_required": false,
    "count": 1199408,
    "name": "c#"
}
```

But if I [use the `fromdate`/`todate` parameters (recent date range)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#fromdate=2018-04-01&todate=2018-04-16&order=desc&sort=popular&tags=c%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), no data is returned.

Please let me know where to change?

Comment: I have experienced the same situation. I think that "fromdate" might be related to the created date of the tag. For example, when the tag's information of ``c#`` is confirmed, the created date is ["9 years, 8 months ago"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info). When [``2008-07-31`` is used as "fromdate"](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#fromdate=2008-07-31&todate=2018-04-17&order=desc&sort=activity&tags=c%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), the results are returned. When ``2008-08-01`` is used, no results are returned. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report on [metase] (or on Stack Apps).

Comment: @Brock Adams Thank you so much for your information. I could study and obtain new information by your comments.

Comment: @Tanaike, Oops. Your original math was correct, tag info pages have [an *additional* bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297857/tag-wiki-stats-created-showing-with-wrong-date-calculation) whereby they display an alleged *tag* creation date ("9 years, 8 months ago"), but the tooltip for that text displays the *wiki* creation date (`2010-07-22 08:48:17`). This is all kinds of messed up.  And the "created" date text is still not reliable.  Can still use [that SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840451/creation-date-for-a-tag?TargTagName=c%23) to drill down.

Comment: @Brock Adams Thank you for more additional information. From the SEDE query, I could confirm it. When I had had the situation, I couldn't notice about the SEDE query. So I had thought that it might be related to the created date of the tag. By your comments, I obtained the additional information for the situation. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is both a bug in the API documentation and a bug in the way [the `/tags/{tags}/info` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name) works.
It is closely related to [this bug on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6687/the-tags-query-is-not-giving-me-the-correct-results-between-two-dates).

The docs don't say it, but the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters **operate on the tag's *creation* date**.

This is really bad behavior because:

1. **None of the `/tags/` routes return creation date**, nor allow sorting on it.
2. There is **no way to even know a tag's creation date**.  [You can only know when the wiki was created (if any) and/or how old the oldest question that ***currently*** has that tag is.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840456/tag-creation-dates)
3. The `/tags/` routes ***do* return the `last_activity_date`**.  So one would think that the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters would operate on it, but they don't.
4. This is not what any reasonable user expects (as demonstrated by both this question and [the cross-site duplicate](https://stackapps.com/questions/6687/the-tags-query-is-not-giving-me-the-correct-results-between-two-dates)).

So:

1. The doc is misleading and/or incomplete about this functionality.
2. The API really should return the creation date and/or apply the  `fromdate` and `todate` parameters to the `last_activity_date`

---

You can get an idea of a tag's (likely) creation date with this SEDE query:
[data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840451/creation-date-for-a-tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840451/creation-date-for-a-tag)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while facing the same issue, but discovered a work around using the `/questions` method instead of /tags.  With this, the `fromdate` and `todate` search parameters can be used along with `tagged`.

Initially this will return much more information than just the total that is needed.  By adjusting the `.wrapper` filters to remove `items` and add `total`, the JSON below is returned for C# tags from 2019-07-01 to 2019-07-08.

[image: Stack Exchange API Filter]

[image: Stack Exchange API Criteria]

```
{
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9783,
  "total": 2266
}
```

API call: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1561939200&todate=1562544000&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=c%23&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--pn9sU*3FRx